# Confusion in REGEXP_SUBSTR In oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am learning REGEXP_SUBSTR in oracle.

I tried :

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR('500 NANDA,KARKI,KUMAR','[^,]+',1,3) from dual;

output is : KUMAR
```

Whatever I understood,I will explain and please correct it if I made mistake.
[^,] -> This comma part will be searched from first part and will reached to `500 NANDA,` part. 
After it will see this `,` then it will try to extract from this part

```
KARKI,KUMAR
```

Like in `substr(string,1,4)` ,1 is the position of first character and  4 is the no of length it will go but what I expect output above was

```
KAR
```

But I got output as `KUMAR`.How it is coming?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your code -

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(
                     '500 NANDA,KARKI,KUMAR'  --string
                    ,'[^,]+'                  -- Pattern (Inside Bracket) to fetch sub-string and + sign denotes anything after the comma
                    ,1                        -- start_position of string to start searching the pattern
                    ,3                        -- Occurrence of the pattern.
                    ) from dual;
```

So 3 specifies to fetch the 3rd part of string after 2nd comma(pattern).

[REGEXP_SUBSTR.](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/regexp_substr.php)

Comment: What is the use of + sign here ?

Comment: hello bro there are just two commas and how is this 3(-- Occurence of the pattern.) working to give me output KUMAR?

Comment: why did you use the caret sign? i have found that if caret sign is used inside the big bracket then it will not match the patter given insdie big barcket.but here how it is getting matched?

Comment: i am talking about caret sign. if caret sign is used inside brackets then it will neglect the content of big bracket yes? for ex: [^A-X] then i see output Y OR Z

Comment: Exactly, So [^,] will tell to fetch everything except a comma.